# Python annotate return type as the type given to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am giving a type to function. The function instantiates the type for me. The type implements `BaseCustomObject` but is one of many possible types.

```
def factory(object_to_create:[T], parameter:int=1) -> [T]:
    constructor_parameter = calculation(parameter)
    return object_to_create(constructor_parameter)

my_custom_object_instance = factory(MyCustomObject)
```

How do I annotate `factory` so that it is clear that it gives back whatever type I send it, and not just `BaseCustomObject`? I prefer not to use a Union type but to have the annotation/inspection/ide understand exactly which specific type I am getting back.

Answer (score 0):

use a TypeVar generic type.
[T] means a list of T, not a T, so dont do that.

If object_to_create is a function, do this.

```
# Use bound to limit the type to a specific ancestor.
T = TypeVar("T", bound="BaseCustomObject") 

# Callable[..., T] is the type of a function 
# that takes in whatever argument and returns an instance of T.

def my_func(
  object_creator: Callable[..., T], 
  params: Optional[int] = 1
) -> T:
  return object_creator(params) # Will return a T.
```

If object_to_create is a `class` and not a function you instead use `Type[T]`which will be the actual class and not a class instance.

```
# Use bound to limit the type to a specific ancestor.
T = TypeVar("T", bound="BaseCustomObject") 

def my_func(
  object_to_create: Type[T], 
  params: Optional[int] = 1
) -> T:
  return object_to_create(params) # Will return an instance of object_to_create.
```